# Incrementing array value in PHP Session variable

Tags: php

I have this array in PHP session, which I want to step through one step at a time.

How do I get the current array index and move one step forward or backward? Here's the code:

```
for ($i = 0; $ < 10; $i++){    
    $result_array[] = $i;   
}

$_SESSION['theValue'] = $result_array;
```

I tried:

```
$_SESSION['theValue'] [0]++;
```

to move the array one step at a time, but it only displays the same value at that index. Is there a way I can keep incrementing the index?

I'm not sure I'm making much sense.

Comment: *to move the array one step at a time* What does this line mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

init session array

```
$_SESSION['theValue'] = $result_array;
$_SESSION['currentIndex'] = 0;
```

create buttons next/previous like this

```
$prev = $_SESSION['currentIndex'] == 0 ? 0 : $_SESSION['currentIndex'] - 1;
$next = $_SESSION['currentIndex'] == sizeof($_SESSION['theValue']) ? $_SESSION['currentIndex'] : $_SESSION['currentIndex'] + 1;
```

and on going to next/previous page, simply increment/decrement `$_SESSION['currentIndex']`

---

usecase:
So when you create link like this:

```
<a href="index.php?page=1">Next</a>
<a href="index.php?page=0">Prev</a>
```

you need to catch the value of `$_GET['page']` and save it to currentIndex session property before rendering content.

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    if(is_numeric($_GET['page']){
        if($_GET['page'] >= 0 && $_GET['page'] <= sizeof($_SESSION['theValue'])){
            $_SESSION['currentIndex'] = $_GET['page'];
        }
    }
}
// place code which works with 'currentIndex' and array in session here...
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but I just keep getting 1 and 0 when I press the prev and next. It does not increment more than 1. Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: and are you saving current value to `currentIndex` session property? you have to save this variable when page reloads

Comment: Thanks again, but how do I save currentIndex and refer to it? Forgive me question.

Comment: @HelenNeely I've gave you example to end of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`$_SESSION['theValue'] [0]++` actually increments the first value in the array rather than incrementing the array index. Use the array functions, and especially [key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) and [next](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php), to navigate through the array.

Or, if you want to keep the last array index in the session, you may want to store the index as a separate session value. The length of the array is read using `count($array)`. The indexes reach from `0` to `count - 1`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly that you want to loop through the array then you should do something like this:

```
$size = count($_SESSION['theValue']);
for($i=0; $i < $size; $i++)
{
    $currentValue = $_SESSION['theValue'][$i];
}
```

Make sure that size is a local variable and you are not using count() directly in the for loop.

Your method of doing $_SESSION['theValue'][0]++ actually increments the value at the zero index.